# Magento SOAP API - PHP Exception error “looks like we got no XML document”

Tags: php, xml, api, magento, soap

We developed an app that pushes and retrieves data from one program to Magento via the Magento API via SOAP, using SOAP 1.1 and Magneto 1.7.0.2.

This is the kind of post we send to the magento store:

> Example:
>   [08/Oct/2013:16:49:59 -0400] "POST /index.php/api/soap/index/ HTTP/1.0" 200 266 "-" "-"

Basically when we attempt to send these commands to the Magneto site / Server
it stops and we receive the following error:

> MAGENTO::ERROR: looks like we got no XML document"

During the connection, the actual return from their magento web service is as follows:

> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home/sistaco5/public_html/includes/src/Jemoon_Htmlminify_Model_Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/sistaco5/public_html/includes/src:.:/usr/local/php53/pear') in /home/sistaco5/public_html/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93

This does not look like an XML.

I believe the error may be related to BOM I found at [this article](http://www.highonphp.com/fixing-soap-exception-no-xml). Not sure if this article will work, but any other thoughts on how to address the above would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This is an older question, but I saw it and thought I might ask questions. My first question is do you get this for all API methods? Have you tried logging into the SOAP API method to get a session value back? If so did you get the same error for that API call? Do you get this error for any other SOAP api calls? Are you using SOAP v1 or v2?

Answer (score 0):

Your error points to missing files in `includes/src/` which are compilation files.

Re-run compilation or disable it. Get to the Magento admin, navigate to `System -> Tools -> Compilation` and do a recompile or disable compilation.

If that page doesn't complete loading, do the compilation via SSH/shell:

- `cd /path/to/magento/root`
- `php -f compiler.php compile` to recompile OR
- `php -f compiler.php disable` to disable/prevent magento from looking in Compilation files.

How odd is it that I'm answering to two questions that have compilation issues in 10 minutes.